# ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1` on my Windows 10 machine and got this error:

> ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires
>   that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
>   environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL:
>   https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

I made all things from:

- official documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
- from here: https://medium.com/@teavanist/install-tensorflow-gpu-on-windows-10-5a23c46bdbc7
- Checked `PATH` variable: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin`
- also have `CUDA_PATH` : `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0` in variables
- file `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin\cudart64_100.dll` exists
- Did system restart

But error still occurs

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like it should be able to find it. Check out the `PATH` that the Python interpreter is seeing in `os.environ['PATH']` (in Python 3 you can read it more easily with `import os; print(*os.environ['PATH'].split(';'), sep='\n')`). If you have just changed the environment variables, you may need to open a new command line or even restart the system.

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks for you comment. I did system restart, that didn't help me. Also I have `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin` in `os.environ['PATH']`

Comment: https://download.mersenne.ca/CUDA-DLLs/CUDA-10.0 In this link you find cudart64_100.dll file. just download it and paste in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin . Your Problem will be solved .
InshaAllah.

Comment: Fixing this leads to another error - `Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'`, [here's an answer with all the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65524506/38368).

Comment: Find my solution to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370496/10477257)

Comment: It's old, but to be correct the link displayed here is the one for CUDA 9.0. The correct one for CUDA 10.0 is here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive. Thanks anyway, your question helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way to fix is to install the latest ‘NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit’, because if it's not there, you'll be missing the 'cudart64_100.dll' library.
The only issue is that the latest copy of CUDA has this particular library upgraded to 'cudart64_101.dll', while the latest TensorFlow still requires the older 'cudart64_100.dll'.
Anyways, one way to deal with this issue is to install the latest CUDA + CUDA from September 2018 and then copy 'cudart64_100.dll' library from old install to the new one.

Or just visit my site where I linked the 'cudart64_100.dll' library downloaded from the CUDA Toolkit 10.0 (Sept 2018), to make it easier to copy it into the latest CUDA directory.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the process: https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/

Comment: The most usefull comment regarding TF2.0 state as of Jan2020. Such a disgrace that TF crashes due to cudart64_101.dll not being cudart64_100.dll. (both CUDA 10.1).

Comment: Note that Tensorflow 2.1–2.2 supports CUDA 10.1 and not 10.2. Not quite the latest CUDA.

Answer (score 12):

I have faced similar issue. I have added the directory of the cudart64_100.dll file to the PATH variable but still it prompts the error "cudart64_100.dll" not found. In the end I finally manage to make it work by adding the following codes. Hope it helps.

```
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\bin\\cudart64_100.dll")
```

Comment: Sad that this ended up being the solution -- but this was the only solution that worked in my case. Reinstalls, restarts, etc. all failed

Comment: How come this has to be the fix? Shouldn't Tensorflow automatically do something like this? How could I get a more permanent solution?

Comment: This solution was the only one that worked for me as well. I had to include all my DLL files like this. I was using the python version installed from the Windows Store... after uninstalling it and installing Python from python.org, I no longer had to include the WinDLL statements.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar error:

> cudart64_101.dll not found

It is because the latest version of *CUDA* requires older `CUDA-version.dll` files to work properly. The solution would be try installing the previous version of *CUDA*.

Once you have downloaded *CUDA 10.1* run the `.exe` file which will first extract the necessary files in `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\CUDA`.

Once the extraction is completed do not proceed with the installation navigate to the directory `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\CUDA\cudart\bin` and here you will find the missing `DLL` file `cudart64_101.dll` and `cudart32_101.dll` copy both the files to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin` and then cancel the installation.

Follow the same steps for any *CUDA* version will work for sure. Hope this helps thank you!!!

Comment: download cudart64_101.dll, cudart32_101.dll --> https://download.mersenne.ca/CUDA-DLLs/CUDA-10.1

Comment: Thanks @Carson, if it wasn't for that link I wouldn't have known which version to get from the Cuda Toolkit Archive here https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT
Every Tensorflow version requires a specific version of CUDA.
The easiest way is to open https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu and read which version did you need.

ex.  CUDA® Toolkit —TensorFlow supports CUDA® 11.2 (TensorFlow >= 2.5.0)

If you want to install Tensor Flow v 2.5.0 you must have exactly CUDA v 11.2 installed.

TensorFlow 2.2 try to import cudart64_101.dll, cusparse64_10.dll and cublas64_10.dll  but they are part from CUDA 10.1 If you have OTHER cuda version will get ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll  as this files are only available in cuda 10.1.

If you want to use older tensorflow version you have to use it with appropriate cuda version

Answer (score 1):

I also was dealing with the current situation that tensorflow expects cudart64_101.dll and NVIDIA offers Version 10.2 as main version (including cudart64_102.dll).

I simply installed both versions. I have both versions in the windows path. Beside disc space, I did not have problems so far and GPU is used in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

**The actual fix is to [download and install CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)**

But if you're in hurry, you can also disable gpu, before importing tensorflow.

```
import os
# BAD IDEA ::::: Disabling gpu . The actual fix is to download and install cuda toolkit.
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the libraries might find a way to solve this issue, but that is not advised, as the root cause for this issue is due to version mismatch of CDNN and cuDNN. It's advised to install the right CDNN and cuDNN versions.

I too have faced similar issues and realized that the issue was with CUDA and CUDNN version mismatch.

Can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) for the proper CDNN and cuDNN versions. From the reference below for TensorFlow 2.4.0 it is recommended to use CUDA 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0.
[image: CUDA & CUDNN reference for TensorFlow]

Or you can refer [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) to download cuDNN for suitable CUDA.
[image: cuDNN for CUDA]

Answer (score 0):

Just rename

```
\program files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\cudart64_102.dll
```

to `cudart100.dll`

Comment: This doesn't really work. It seems to load but there are run time errors later. Better downgrade to 10.0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the  cudart64_100.dll  file in this website [link](https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/).
and extract it, add cudart64_100.dll to your **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin**
after you run your python script you will see:
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll

Answer (score 0):

NVidia maintains a download archive of older CUDA driver releases.  I would recommend downloading the installer from here instead of a third-party archive:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

That page has a link to a page for downloading version 10.0:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive

For the CUDA-NN libraries, the archive may be found here:

https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

You need to be a member of the NVidia developer program to access this archive, but it is free to sign-up.

There should be no problem installing multiple versions at once, since the CUDA installer uses a separate installation directory for each version and the library files have different names.  You will, however, want to select a custom installation to avoid replacing your display drivers, since you're installing older versions.

The CUDA-NN libraries (at least for Windows) are distributed as zip files.  Copy the contents where you would like them (I installed each as a subdirectory under the corresponding CUDA driver installation directory).

Finally, add all of the various CUDA and CUDA-NN directories to your PATH, if they aren't already there so Python and Tensorflow can find them.