# ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, cuda

I got a problem for cuda installation. Can anyone help me to sove this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igWZg.png)

I use tensorflow 1.14.0, python 3.7, cuda version 10.0.0 and cudnn version 7.4. When  I'm going to train model, I got the error about this "ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: [https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive"](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive%22). Can anyone help me to deal this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest CUDA + CUDA from September 2018 and then copy 'cudart64_100.dll' library from old install to the new one.

In details it is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58464975/15703151