# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll' on tensorflow CPU-only installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I just installed the latest version of Tensorflow via `pip install tensorflow` and whenever I run a program, I get the log message:

> W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

Is this bad? How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

## Tensorflow 2.1+

### What's going on?

With the [new Tensorflow 2.1 release](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.1.0), the default `tensorflow` pip package contains both CPU and GPU versions of TF. In previous TF versions, not finding the CUDA libraries would emit an error and raise an exception, while now the library dynamically searches for the correct CUDA version and, if it doesn't find it, emits the warning (The **W** in the beginning stands for warnings, errors have an **E** (or **F** for fatal errors) and falls back to CPU-only mode. In fact, this is also written in the log as an info message right after the warning (do note that if you have a higher minimum log level that the default, you might not see info messages). The full log is (emphasis mine):

> 2020-01-20 12:27:44.554767: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
>
> 2020-01-20 12:27:44.554964: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] **Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.**

### Should I worry? How do I fix it?

If you don't have a CUDA-enabled GPU on your machine, or if you don't care about not having GPU acceleration, no need to worry. If, on the other hand, you installed tensorflow and wanted GPU acceleration, check your CUDA installation (TF 2.1 requires CUDA **10.1**, *not* 10.2 or 10.0).

If you just want to get rid of the warning, you can [adapt TF's logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information) to suppress warnings, but that might be overkill, as it will silence *all* warnings.

---

## Tensorflow 1.X or 2.0:

Your CUDA setup is broken, ensure you have the correct version installed.

Comment: Thanks. But I add another point: If you installed python from **Microsoft Store**, you may still see this issue, even if you've done the required steps! See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63547977/5318303).

Comment: I uninstalled every component of CUDA and still got the same error as if CUDA still existed

Comment: @pete the error appears if it can't find the right CUDA version. Since you uninstalled it, of course it won't find it and print the error... That's the normal behaviour.

Comment: @brainslugs83 CUDA minor versions are not interchangeable, that's a limitation coming from CUDA itself

Comment: Is there a better way to avoid those warnings on import time? without affecting TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVE. 
Or modify those warnings from stderr to stdout?

Answer (score 77):

To install the prerequisites for GPU support in TensorFlow 2.1:

1. Install your latest GPU drivers.
2. Install [CUDA 10.1](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base).

   - If the CUDA installer reports "you are installing an older driver version", you may wish to choose a custom installation and deselect some components. Indeed, note that software bundled with CUDA including GeForce Experience, PhysX, a Display Driver, and Visual Studio integration are not required by TensorFlow.
   - Also note that TensorFlow requires a specific version of the CUDA Toolkit unless you build from source; for TensorFlow 2.1 and 2.2, this is currently version 10.1.
3. Install cuDNN.

   1. [Download cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) v7.6.4 for CUDA 10.1. This will require you to sign up to the NVIDIA Developer Program.
   2. Unzip to a suitable location and add the bin directory to your PATH.
4. Install tensorflow by `pip install tensorflow`.
5. You [may need to restart your PC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112550/604687).

Comment: Thanks. But I add another point: If you installed python from **Microsoft Store**, you may still see this issue, even if you've done the required steps! See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63547977/5318303).

Comment: 6. Restart your IDE after modifying the PATH variable.

Comment: Note: I was a bit confused that after installing the latest GPU drivers, `nvidia-smi` showed me `CUDA Version: 11.2` (CUDA 11 is needed for TF 2.4) but the real installed and used CUDA version by my TF was 10.1. So never skip the CUDA installation step and always ensure your PATH is correctly set up.

Comment: Wow, restarting my pc could have saved me 2h. Thanks :)

Answer (score 32):

TensorFlow 2.3.0 works fine with CUDA 11. But you have to install tf-nightly-gpu (after you installed tensorflow and CUDA 11):
https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu/

Try:

```
pip install tf-nightly-gpu
```

Afterwards you'll get the message in your console:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I was going to have to roll back to 10.1.

Comment: Thank you! "pip install tf-nightly" did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you! This was my only solution after trying for more than 15 hours.

Comment: Had to do four steps: 1) Install `tf-nightly-gpu`, 2) install latest nvidia cuda toolkit (11.2+) using custom install but don't overwrite newer drivers (unselect), 3) Restart terminal. 4) Reinstall Nvidia driver if above steps borked it. e.g. nvidia-smi results in `Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system`.

Comment: In March 2021, tensorflow new version is stated to be compatible with cuda 11, and I don't feel fine at using a nightly tensorflow-gpu version, it sounds like a hack. Nonetheless, this was the only solution working

Answer (score 21):

I solved this another way.
First of all I installed cuda 10.1 toolkit from this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base).

Where I selected installer type: [exe(local)](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal) (for windows) and installed 10.1 in custom mode (without visual studio integration, NVIDIA PhysX because previously I installed CUDA 10.2 so required dependencies were installed automatically)

After installation, From the Following Path
(`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin`)
, in my case, I copied `cudart64_101.dll` file and pasted in
(`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin`).

Then importing Tensorflow worked smoothly.

Comment: I've had the same problem when using Conda env. The solution was the same: copied the Dlls mentioned in the warning from "...\Anaconda\Envs\<myEnv>\Library\bin" to the "...\Anaconda3\Library\bin"
The required Dlls should be in a path that os knows about it.

Comment: Just a note: Adding the folder `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin` to `PATH` would've worked as well (and is the recommended way to go, to avoid messing up with CUDA installations)

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal Better use the NVIDIA site for downloading the .dll file.

Answer (score 17):

**In my case the tensorflow install was looking for cudart64_101.dll**

[image]

The 101 part of cudart64_101 is the Cuda version - here 101 = 10.1

I had downloaded 11.x, so the version of cudart64 on my system was cudart64_110.dll

[image]

**This is the wrong file!! cudart64_101.dll ≠ cudart64_110.dll**

## Solution

Download Cuda 10.1 from https://developer.nvidia.com/

Install (mine crashes with NSight Visual Studio Integration, so I switched that off)

[image]

When the install has finished you should have a Cuda 10.1 folder, and in the bin the dll the system was complaining about being missing

[image]

Check that the path to the 10.1 bin folder is registered as a system environmental variable, so it will be checked when loading the library

[image]

**You may need a reboot if the path is not picked up by the system straight away**

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that a reboot was needed in my case after installing CUDA 11.0 to get tensorflow to find it (cudart64_xyz.DLL requires CUDA version xy.z, in my case, xyz=110, not 101)

Answer (score 13):

In a `conda` environment, this is what solved my problem (I was missing `cudart64-100.dll`:

1. Downloaded it from
   [dll-files.com/CUDART64_100.DLL](https://www.dll-files.com/search/?q=CUDART64_100.DLL)
2. Put it in my conda environment at
   `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\envs\<env name>\Library\bin`

That's all it took! You can double check if it's working:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Comment: If you installed CUDA 10.1 for example you probably already have the DLL in "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\cudart64_101.dll". I'm personally averse to downloading DLLs from secondary sources.

Comment: For me, the directory location is C:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\<env name>\Library\bin

Answer (score 6):

**This answer might be helpful if you see above error but actually you have CUDA 10 installed:**

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
```

output:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
```

which was the solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

I installed cudatoolkit 11 and copy dll
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin` to `C:\Windows\System32`.
It fixed for PyCharm but not for Anaconda jupyter:

> [name: "/device:CPU:0" device_type: "CPU" memory_limit: 268435456
> locality { } incarnation: 6812190123916921346 , name: "/device:GPU:0"
> device_type: "GPU" memory_limit: 13429637120 locality {   bus_id: 1
> links {   } } incarnation: 18025633343883307728 physical_device_desc:
> "device: 0, name: Quadro P5000, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute
> capability: 6.1" ]

Comment: Thank you, copying the dll file there worked great:
 tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

Answer (score 4):

This [solution](https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/) worked for me :

I preinstalled the environnement with anaconda (here is the code)

```
conda create -n YOURENVNAME python=3.6 // 3.6> incompatible with keras
conda activate YOURENVNAME
conda install tensorflow-gpu
conda install -c anaconda keras
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
conda install matplotlib
```

but after I had still these warnings

```
2020-02-23 13:31:44.910213: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

2020-02-23 13:31:44.925815: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll

2020-02-23 13:31:44.941384: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll

2020-02-23 13:31:44.947427: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll

2020-02-23 13:31:44.965893: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll

2020-02-23 13:31:44.982990: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll

2020-02-23 13:31:44.990036: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
```

How I solved the first warning :
I just download a zip file wich contained all the cudnn files (dll, etc) here : https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

How I solved the second warning :
I looked the last missing file (cudart64_101.dll) in my virtual env created by conda and I just copy/pasted it in the same lib folder than for the .dll cudnn

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow 2.1 works with Cuda 10.1.

If you want a quick hack:

- Just download `cudart64_101.dll` from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/cudart64_101.dll.html). Extract the zip file and copy the `cudart64_101.dll` to your CUDA `bin` directory

Else:

- Install Cuda 10.1

Comment: Where is located the cuda `bin` directory?

Comment: Recommending that people install an executable from an unofficial source is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Tensorflow gpu 2.2 and 2.3 nightly

(along CUDA Toolkit 11.0 RC)

To solve the same issue as OP, I just had to find *cudart64_101.dll* on my disk (in my case **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvStreamSrv**) and add it as variable environment (that is add value **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\Corporation\NvStreamSrv)cudart64_101.dll** to user's environment variable **Path**).

Answer (score 3):

This is just a `W`arning and `I`nformation message that CUDA libraries cannot be found.

If you are using NVIDIA GPU, you can refer to how to install the missing files.

If you don't use NVIDIA GPU, or simply want to ignore the `I` and `W` messages, you can add the 2 lines below at the beginning of your code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

> You can see more about `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` at [TensorFlow logging](https://deepreg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/logging.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

download CUDA Toolkit 11.0 RC

To solve the issue,
I just find cudart64_101.dll on my disk
( C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvStreamSrv) and add it as variable environment that is add value (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\Corporation\NvStreamSrv)cudart64_101.dll to user's environment variable Path).

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by the version of python you are running as well, I was using the python 3.7 from the microsoft store and I run into this error, switching to python 3.10 fixed it.

Comment: I suspect the issue was the fact that you used the Microsoft store python. I vaguely remember something about it having some issues

Comment: Yes, I this answer just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636785/tensorflow-not-recognising-cudart64-101-dll/63547977#63547977 

but I remember having issue with another version of python that was from the offical site, caused by the change of how dll are loaded in 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix the issue by updating NVIDIA device drivers to the latest (v446.14).
NVIDIA drivers download [link here](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when mixing pip & conda to get tensorflow 2.3 installed.  (I used pip to install tensorflow 2.3 b/c at the time conda's install of tensorflow 2.3 was broken.)

I ended up with the incorrect versions of cudatoolkit and cudnn installed.

To solve the problem, I simply did `conda install` with specific versions of cudatoolkit and cuda specified.

Look at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?force_isolation=true#tested_build_configurations for info on tensorflow, cudatoolkit, and cuda versions that should work together.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error here with tensorboard , it happen after I update the GPU driver
the thing is i was running tensorboard from the cmd where I didn't install any CUDA since I was using anaconda
`when you install TensorFlow using anaconda all the required cuda and cudnn are downloaded for you`  you will miss the files if you didn't use anaconda env where you install TensorFlow in it

[image]

### Solution

#### * just open tensoboard from anaconda

#### 1-or just download the last Cuda toolkit and add it to paths

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

and use this
2-`conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit`

3-then restart your pc

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced similar issues and realized that the issue was with CUDA and CUDNN version mismatch.

Can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) for the proper versions. From the reference below for TensorFlow 2.4.0 it is recommended to use CUDA 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0.
[image: CUDA & CUDNN reference for TensorFlow]

Or you can refer [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) to download cuDNN for suitable CUDA.
[image: cuDNN for CUDA]

Answer (score -4):

A simpler way would be to create a link called `cudart64_101.dll` to point to `cudart64_102.dll`. This is not very orthodox but since TensorFlow is looking for `cudart64_101.dll` exported symbols and the nvidia folks are not amateurs, they would most likely not remove symbols from 101 to 102. It works, based on this assumption (mileage may vary).

Comment: This is a terrible idea, CUDA minor versions (i.e., 10.1, 10.2, etc) are not compatible with each other. Linking to 10.2 "as if" it was 10.1 will cause random crashes (that's assuming the DLL loads at all). Besides, this implies you installed cuda 10.2 on your machine, which for a CPU-only installation is not necessary

Comment: of course it is not necessary for cpu only. as far as 10.2 being completely different than 10.1 and random crashes, i would recommend you learn about dynamic linking and exported symbols

Comment: the dll loads and works just fine (for your information)

Comment: but end users should install prescribed dynamic libraries, especially if they are not sure what this is all about

Comment: "of course it's not necessary for CPU-only": read again the question title.