# Tensorflow not recognising cudart64_101.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

I have a DLL file in the path: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\cudart64_101.dll`, but `TensorFlow` doesn't seem to recognize it:

```
2020-03-11 14:39:19.815880: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
```

I made sure that the PATH variable contains the path to the DLL:

```
>>> l = os.environ['PATH'].split(';')
>>> for s in l:
...     print(s)
...
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
```

The weird part is that if I include it manually with `ctypes` it gets loaded successfully:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\bin\\cudart64_101.dll")
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-03-11 15:05:26.907300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
```

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: @Veeru I have cuda 10.1 and 10.2 installed (10.2 in use on my OS, while tf 2.1.0 supports cuda 10.1). Maybe that is the problem? How can I solve that?

Comment: At this point i would recommend to completely remove both CUDA packages (10.1 and 10.2), as it is probably not a good idea to have both at the same time. After de-installing, make sure you check all your folders so that nothing is left. Please follow the installation instructions for Windows at https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781

Comment: @Omer Lubin, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above. Else, can you share the current state so that i can help you. Thanks !

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it, @OmerLubin?

Comment: @revy I did not. I gave up and installed the tensorflow docker. If you are not familiar with docker, you can think of dockers as small light-weight virtual machines. The tensorflow docker is already set up, and only requires you to install the docker software  and the NVIDIA Docker Support. You can read about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: @OmerLubin, thank you for your suggestion. I managed to solve it by downgrading the Python version (3.8 > 3.7). Although the cudart64_101.dll problem was fixed, I'm still having other issues (maybe due to compatibility reasons).

Comment: I finally got it working thanks to hint to check windows PATH. My CUDA 11.1 installation had put itself on the PATH and the PATH entry was still there even after uninstalling CUDA 11.1,  and the 10.1 installer did not put itself on the PATH during installation. Finally after laboriously adding %CUDA_PATH%/bin (don't forget the /bin!!) to the Windows user PATH, it worked and pycharm can once again import TF2.3.1 and find the cuda runtime DLL.  BTW I recommend Rapid environment editor for windows users who need to frequently touch PATH or other vars (https://www.rapidee.com/en/about)

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the problem was from *the python was installed from **Windows Store***!

See [@smreichling](https://github.com/smreichling)'s comment on [tensorflow's GitHub (issue 36111)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36111#issuecomment-614933000):

> The problem turned out to be that the version of python I had installed was the one from the Microsoft Store and *not* the one from python.org. As it turns out, apps installed from the Microsoft Store are sandboxed. Windows restricts where they can load DLLs from pretty severely. Among the [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order): Windows does not search the directories in the `PATH` env var for the DLLs. So app store python will never be able to find CUDA DLLs this way.

So I installed the one that's downloadable from https://www.python.org.