# cudart64_101.dll error still showing with path variables setup in tensorflow gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have looked through the similar questions on this topic and have put these in my path:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\lib\x64

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\cuda\bin
```

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0 in sublime text 3 for python 3.8.5.

The error I am getting is:

```
2020-08-28 22:32:53.523625: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-08-28 22:32:53.523856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Any help with this issue and explanation of why it is not working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install useful in case of you ?

Comment: Is the GPU you are using Cuda compatible?

Comment: @ashraful I have previously read through this article but after looking at further comments I think the issue is that I downloaded python from the Microsoft store as opposed to the python website. I'll try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636785/tensorflow-not-recognising-cudart64-101-dll/63547977#63547977 Cheers.

Comment: @AniketBote Yes