# Trouble activating Tensorflow 2.0 on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

This has been asked countless times here, but I could not find solution that fits my problem.
I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu on Windows 10, Anaconda. I downloaded CUDA (Version 10.2) and CuDNN, I have moved files from CuDNN library to CUDA folders and added following variables to PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp
```

After running following code in anaconda, I get following response:

`from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
 print(device_lib.list_local_devices())`

[image: message]
I am guessing the main problem is `"Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found"`, so I went to my CUDA bin folder and there is no `cudart64_101.dll`, but there is `cudart64_102.dll`. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Here's a reference you could take. It might because of your CUDA being broken. [Cudart64-101-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last three numbers in your .dll files should point you to a solution. TensorFlow is looking for CUDA 10.1, but you have installed CUDA 10.2.

Re-installing CUDA and the compatible cuDNN should fix your problem. See [the TensorFlow installation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) for the exact versions of CUDA and cuDNN.
You'll probably have to reinstall TF as well, after installing the correct CUDA libraries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to download CUDA 10.1 now, but I am getting installation error from NVIDIA. I'll see what can be done

Comment: apparently CUDA 10.2 was causing some problems when I tried reinstalling 10.1 version. I did manual download and installed only CUDA (no drivers etc. stuff which usually comes when installing CUDA) and it worked