# I am facing an error while importing tensorflow 2.0.0

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow through anaconda using the following code: -

```
conda install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

But I am not able to import it and the following error is popping up: -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
<module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py 
in <module>
 27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
 29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py 
in swig_import_helper()
 23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, 
description)
 25             finally:

~\anaconda3\envs\iNeuron\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\anaconda3\envs\iNeuron\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I have tried multiple ways by downgrading the tensorflow version but nothing seems to work.
Request someone to help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093510/error-while-installing-tensorflowavx-support-and-cpuid-python) I had similar issue and managed to find out the solution eventually. Try these steps and if you have any question write in comment I am more than happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to copy these packages:

- `libcrypto-1_1-x64.*`
- `libssl-1_1-x64.*`

from `Anaconda3\Library\bin` to your `Anaconda3\DLLs` folder.

Comment: I didn't get you. Bu copying u mean to post it here for your reference?