# Face recognition environment preparation problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I have a problem preparing the environment for face recognition, I install TensorFlow GPU, Cuda 10.0, cuDNN, vs community 2019 and c++ libraries from vs. and I got this problem

[image]

Comment: Helpful if you could actually copy-paste the error message. Unable to read tiny text on image

Answer (score 0):

If you've just installed the drivers,

1. Restart your PC. (Must)
2. Run `nvidia-smi`, if this command fails to execute, you have to install the suitable nvidia drivers.

There is a similar thread open for tf cpu, you could check this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install)

Comment: this command `nvidia-smi` worked successfully, what can I do now