# TensorFlow doesn't works

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have to use tensorflow in a course that I'm doing so I tried to install it but the result is allways an error. I tried differents ways, and the closer that I have been from install tensorflow is through changing the top left button "Applications on" in Anaconda Navigator to tf. The result is the next

```
import tensorflow as tf

2021-01-04 14:36:46.204862: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-01-04 14:36:46.205115: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import compat

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import compat

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import v1

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import lite

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import experimental

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import nn

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\lite\experimental\nn\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python.lite import TFLiteLSTMCell

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python.convert import build_toco_convert_protos  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python import util

  File "C:\Users\marioc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\util.py", line 30, in <module>
    import flatbuffers

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flatbuffers'
```

I'm using Spyder 4.1.5 and python 3.8.5 64 bits by the way

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? I'll really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: you can install this via **pip install flatbuffers** just keep in mind that you are installing in the same environment and for conda environment you have to do  **conda install -c conda-forge python-flatbuffers**

Comment: You need to install `flatbuffers`, since you are using anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge flatbuffers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows try to install this:

[VC_redist.x64.exe](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d60aa805-26e9-47df-b4e3-cd6fcc392333/7D7105C52FCD6766BEEE1AE162AA81E278686122C1E44890712326634D0B055E/VC_redist.x64.exe)

Comment: Now I get the next error:
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install