# Persisting Error/Warning with Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

the problem I'm persistently getting from just writing (in Python3, also using Anaconda JupyterLab)

```py
import tensorflow
```

I have checked environment variables and confirmed its Path, I've activated the environment, I've tried so much and nothing has worked. I'm not sure how I can proceed at all with this issue. Please help.

```
2021-04-19 20:55:05.873366: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2021-04-19 20:55:05.873455: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a GPU setup on your machine, you can ignore this message. This is a warning message that is shown by TensorFlow. However, if you have a GPU enabled system and you want to install the GPU version of TensorFlow (provided you have a GPU that is supported), you will need to investigate further. For a more detailed explanation, refer here:

[Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll' on tensorflow CPU-only installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install)