# How can I fix cudart64_110.dll error which caused from Tensorflow in Pycharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have a problem about fixing `cudart64_110.dll` error which caused by Tensorflow in Pycharm.

In order to fix it, I downloaded its file from this link which is shown below.

```
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork
```

However, it still shows this kind of error.

Here is my code which is shown below.

```
# Import TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Here is my warning issue which is shown below.

```
2021-06-09 22:08:07.032388: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-06-09 22:08:07.033945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Here is my path to show the support of a cudo on my computer.

[Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4VIq.jpg)

How can I fix it?

Comment: which GPU are you trying to use?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy nvidia geforce gtx 1650 ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cudart64_110.dll`

You need the CUDA installation for 11.0 (“...110.dll”). You have 10.1 right now, which was what was necessary for the person who asked for “...101.dll” in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install) I’m guessing you read, but is not useful for you.

Comment: This file(`cudart64_101.dll`) is already located at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvStreamSrv` . Here is the image link : https://imgur.com/MzQOoSt

Comment: You do not need `cudart64_101.dll`. You need `cudart64_110.dll`. The number is different.

Comment: The link is it https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. Is it right?

Comment: You should use this: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive