# Trying to use tensorflow with GPU but got "Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'", I have cudatool kit and cuDNN installed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda, conv-neural-network, cudnn

I'nm new to the tensorflow and I'm trying to train a CNN for image classification.
Here is the error I got:

```
2022-11-15 11:18:50.087877: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-11-15 11:18:50.088548: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
nd
2022-11-15 11:19:04.824435: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found2022-11-15 11:19:04.824617: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found2022-11-15 11:19:04.824783: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found      
2022-11-15 11:19:04.825030: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found2022-11-15 11:19:04.825218: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found2022-11-15 11:19:04.825408: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found      
2022-11-15 11:19:04.825483: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

I do have GPU available and CUDA version is 11.2[Here is what I got when I checking the CUDA version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWoBT.png)
[Here is my tf version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRVu2.png)

Tried to many methods but still not working, no idea waht's going on.
Really appreciate for your help.

Followed the instruction on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip couple times.

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59823283/

Answer (score 1):

My problem just solved. Did couple research and find the problem might  caused by installing Tensorflow with cmd.

1. Make sure you install the cuDNN correctly.
2. find the "cudart64_110.dll" file located in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin`.
3. Copy and paste that .dll file to `C:\Windows\System32`

This method works for me, hope anyone can find it helpful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910708/

Comment: That link doesn't work for my case. Already saw that before I posted the question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -2):

try 'nvidia-smi -L' I try and check with the compatibility matrix from the Nvidia website **515.43.04+ (CUDA 11.7)**    [CUDA and Driver compatibility](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html)

> Version   Python version  Compiler    Build tools cuDNN   CUDA
>
> 2.10.0__    3.7-3.10_______       GCC 9.3.1   Bazel 5.1.1 __ **8.1**_  _ **11.2**

1. Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py OR
   https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. python get-pip.py
3. Install MSYS2 :
   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_msys2
4. Install Visual C++ Build Tools 2019 : https://www.msys2.org/

____________Pre-Installation: Add this to system PATH

____________a. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\bin

____________b. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\extras\CUPTI\lib64

____________c. F:\msys64\mingw64\bin

____________d. F:\msys64\usr\bin

5. python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
6. python3 -m pip install -U six numpy wheel packaging
7. python3 -m pip install -U keras_preprocessing --no-deps
8. python3 -m pip install tensorflow
9. python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu

Ref[0]: [Tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: You can use pip or pip3 that is my mistakes since I run on native Windows 10, I fixed the link to the same sources.