# Tensorflow: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, conda

When I'm trying to run my Tensorflow code inside my conda environment `myEnv001`, I got the error message `dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found`. I'm aware that my error is similar to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install), which says I didn't install CUDA.

I have CUDA 10.1 installed, but anyway I tried to re-install CUDA 10.1 for `myEnv001`. I ran below at my terminal, and CUDA 10.1 is installed successfully in `myEnv001`

```
> conda activate myEnv001
(myEnv001) > conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.1
```

But when I tried to run my Tensorflow code I still have the same error message... How can I fix it?

**My library**

- `conda`: `4.10.1`
- `Tensorflow` installed in myEnv001: `2.6.0`
- `cudatoolkit` installed in myEnv001: `10.1.243`

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your reply. I just installed CUDA 11.0 in `myEnv001`. But then the error message says `dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found` (i.e. another file is missing). Any ideas?

Comment: No, you need CUDA 11.2, remove that 11.0 and install 11.2. You also need to have cuDNN  8.1. Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) link, there is a table at the very end of that page. Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for `TF 2.6`, the compatible `CUDA` is `11.2` and `cuDNN` is `8.1`.

For the benefit of community providing compatibility versions are as shown below

[image]

For more details, you can refer [windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations) and [Linux/macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) tested build configurations for CPU and GPU.