# I work on python code , i don't complete because this problem

Tags: python, css

W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64\_101.dll' on tensorflow CPU-only installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import os

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'