# SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Raise ValueError(f'Unknown heatmap type - {self._box_heatmap_type}')^

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm following this [TensorFlow guide](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) for object detection models and I've gotten to part 6, which is training your program. I've input this line of code,

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

But it keeps resulting in the syntax error here.

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
2022-09-16 14:38:10.767310: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2022-09-16 14:38:10.767443: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 53, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 34, in <module>
    from object_detection.core import target_assigner
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\core\target_assigner.py", line 1051
    raise ValueError(f'Unknown heatmap type - {self._box_heatmap_type}')
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's happened before but I managed to fix it by going back to the file and editting the changes it asks for. But this time, if I take away that quote it's on, the whole line has a red squiggly. I've never used Python or Anaconda before, and this is my first time touching it. Any help would be appreciated. I've read online this is due to my Python being an older version, and that line of code doesn't work with the old version. I think I'm using 3.5, but I'm not sure if updating the version will break everything, because I think TensorFlow only works with 3.5

Comment: Just checked - Python 3.5.6

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/ indicates `tensorflow` works for Python 3.7 though 3.10 (the current release). You should really upgrade from Python 3.5.

Comment: Python 3.5 was only fully supported until August 2017, and stopped receiving security fixes nearly 2 years ago. Even Python 3.7 reach end-of-support over 2 years go and will stop receiving security fixes in June 2023. I would recommend switching to Python 3.10 now.

Comment: So this means it will be safe to switch to Python 10? Will it break anything? Will it mess with any older versions of other things I have installed?

Comment: You should install Python 3.10 and test your code, but code written for Python 3.5 should at least be *syntactiaclly* compatible with Python 3.10.

Comment: Do we need to upgrade TensforFlow as well?

Comment: Maybe? I don't know what version of TensorFlow you are using. This is not the place for a full tutorial on using Python.

Answer (score 0):

f-strings were not introduced until after python 3.5, you'll need to use an older syntax. Use:

`raise ValueError('Unknown heatmap type - {}'.format(self._box_heatmap_type))`

or something similar.

Comment: I used else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown heatmap type - {}".format(self._box_heatmap_type)) and it worked! Edit: But it did give me another error that I have to fix, but MANY MANY thanks on this solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is that the training stage is not being allowed to be processed through **`GPU`** which returns a warning

`2022-09-16 14:38:10.767310: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found`

I would recommend you read the section of the link you shared that indicates how to upgrade **cudCNN** for [DLL errors](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#6-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found---or-other-dll-related-errors):

```
conda create -n tensorflow2 pip python=3.5
```

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

if this doesn't work you can try using a different pipeline configuration, for that you need to replace the pipeline config parameter
`--pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

with this `TPU` compatible [pipeline configuration file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config) `--pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config`

you can also try to add a new parameter, `--use_tpu=true` (if available).

also see:

- [TPU Compatible detection pipelines](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tpu_compatibility.md)
- [Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll' #40804](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40804)
- [Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll' on tensorflow CPU-only installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823283/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-101-dll-on-tensorflow-cpu-only-install)